# Cursor position is not proper : Edittext (gravity:right) when empty

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have set right gravity to `edittext` , and hint as 0 as below

```
<com.components.MyFontEdittextView
      android:id="@+id/etPessanger"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@null"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:hint="0"
      android:gravity="right"
      android:inputType="numberSigned"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:minLines="1"
      android:paddingLeft="5dp"
      android:paddingRight="5dp"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:textColor="@color/color_black"
      android:textColorHint="@color/color_app_label"
      android:textSize="16.52sp"
      tools:text="3" />
```

but when `edittext` is empty and hint is visible then it shows cursor position like this:

[image]

I want cursor at the end of hint.(at end of 0)
Any solution?

Comment: The cursor will not visible in hint

Comment: Or you can set `etPessanger.setSelection(etPessanger.getText().length())`

Comment: try this - android:textAlignment="viewStart" and
android:textDirection="rtl"

Comment: Cursor appears at the place text will start to appear and is at start of hint, Try setting text "0" instead of hint and remove it later.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using below way.

add `android:text="0"` and remove `android:hint="0"`

And in Your activity code

```
etPessanger.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus) {
                    //Remove 0 from edittext and set empty in edittext
                    if(etPessanger.getText().toString().equals("0")) {
                        etPessanger.setText("");
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```